# How can I store user input on a variable to using it as a parameter in a bat file?

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd

I wanted to know how can I store what the user types as path in a variables, then use this variables as parameters in a php script that i've done.

To explain better what I'm doing here, I got an php script that takes 3 arguments, I'm asking to the user to give the path of the script (I ask this because the script will be used by a lot of other users so it will not be on the same folder all the times, but the script name will be the same), then I ask the path of both files with the respective name and finally the folder path when the result file will be generated.

```
@echo off
PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.33

set /p pathscript=Script path : 
set /p path1=Path of first file :
set /p name1=File n1 name :
set /p path2=Path of second file :
set /p name2=File n2 name :
set /p pathresult=Path where the result file will be generated :

REM Execute
php "%pathscript%"/script.php "%path1%"/"%name1" "%path2%"/"%name2%" "%pathresult%"
echo !
pause
```

But I got an error, like the arguments are missing, can someone help me?

Comment: Looks like your code is almost complete!
You should remove quotation marks from batch variables where it is not mandatory If it doesn’t work, would you mind posting the exact error code?

Comment: `%name1` should read `%name1%`, right?

Comment: @MaximChernitsky, so you are assuming that if a path does not have spaces in it, the command will not want double quotes? That is a rather odd thing to assume. If the command supports double quotes, you give it, whether your path has spaces or not.

Comment: No need to ask the user, where the batch file is stored: `set "pathscript=%~dp0"` (note that `%~dp0` always contains a trailing backslash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
php "%pathscript:/=\%\script.php" "%path1:/=\%\%name1" "%path2:/=\%\%name2%" "%pathresult%"
```

That is, quote the entire path, not the individual elements, and use the correct path-separator. The `:/=\` should do the translation should you enter `/`. Note that in Windows, `/` introduces switches.

I've no ide what `php` expects as parameters - posting the error message verbatim instead of vaguely referencing it would have taken less time and been more helpful.

Comment: That's why I was searching for ! Thank youuu !!